# Form using server's rewrite

Tags: html, nginx

I have this form:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="search">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="$get.q.htmlentities();" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
```

Is it possible for me to tell it to go to `http://site.com/search/my+search+string`
instead of having it go to `http//site.com/search.php?q=my+search+string`

I have the nginx rewrite working, but how can I get to form to go to that url?

Comment: the browser will go to whatever url you specific in the `action=""` attribute.

Comment: yes, but I want to replace the default `?q=` with a `/` when the submit button is pressed

Comment: then you'll have to use JS to catch the submit and build the url yourself. standard GET form submission procedure is to use query parameters, e.g. `?var=val&var=val`... this isn't something you can alter without JS intercepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you will want to do a javascript manipulation to change the action attribute of the form after the submit is clicked, the allow the borwser to go to the desred URL.

I would not utilize a server-side rewrite in this case as that will just double the number of requests the server needs to handle.

Comment: That is really the only solution outside of just handling with rewrites on the server side.